# sed match first word replace full line

Tags: sed

I know this should be straight forward but I'm stuck, sorry.

I have two files both contain the same parameters but with different values.  I'm trying to read one file line at a time, get the parameter name, use this to match in the second file and replace the whole line with that from file 1.

e.g. rw_2.core.fvbCore.Param.isEnable 1  (FVB_Params)
becomes 
rw_2.core.fvbCore.Param.isEnable true    (FVB_Boolean)

The lines are not always the same length but I always want to replace the whole line.

The code I have is as follows but it doesn't make the substitutions and I can't work out why not.

```
while read line; do         
   ParamName=`awk '{print $1}'`  
   sed -i 's/$ParamName.*/$line/g' FVB_Params.txt
done < FVB_Boolean.txt
```

Comment: `.^` ?? How should that make sense? You say there is a character before the starting of the line?

Comment: Yeah, sorry that was a typo, can't work out how to edit this. Ignore the characters before $ParamName

Comment: Edited to correct

Answer (score 0):

You need your sed command within double quotes if you want those variables to be replaced with their values.  You have single quotes, so sed is actually looking for strings with dollar signs to replace with the string '$line', not whatever your shell has in the $line variable.

In short, sed's not seeing the values you want.  Switch to double quotes.